# Jquery UI .position() on fixed element

Tags: jquery-ui, positioning

Jquery UI's .position() function seems broken on elements that are fixed while scrolling. For example I'm trying to position a new element (the blue block in the demo below) at the "center top" of a fixed element at the top of a page (like a header). I expected the collision detection in .position() would have the element flipped to the "center bottom". It works the first time, but if someone scrolls part way downt he page, it's totally broken.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lrocksmashtime/MJwdP/

To see the effect try clicking "click" both when you haven't scrolled the result window, and then click it again after scrolling a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Your code:

```
my: "bottom",
at: "top",
```

Can be read as: Position "my" element bottom "at" target element top

The correct code is:

```
my: "top",
at: "bottom",
```

Can be read as: Position “my” element top "at" target element bottom

This works as you expect: http://jsfiddle.net/MJwdP/18/

Comment: I appreciate the reply, can't believe I didn't see it until now. However, it doesn't address my initial question concerning the automatic collision detection. It is clear that the blue box isn't going to fit at the top. My initial call to .position forces the collision detection to move the box to the bottom of the target. If you scroll the page down, the box gets positioned at the top despite not being visible. It occurs to me now that this really isn't a bug, but it would be nice if the collision detection took into account the visibility of the element being positioned.